# How to put bootstrap glow (used in the 'form-control' CSS class) on a div?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a web page that has multiple `divs` which works like informing boxes for the user.

All I want is when the user puts its mouse arrow inside an informing-box (hovers its mouse over the div) to display the glow on this `div` like the above input text provides when you clicking on it. When the user exits the region of this `div`, the glow must be disappear.

How can I do that?

EDIT: My question seems to be the same with the other article's, but it's NOT! I want the same effect of the text input to be added on the div (same color, same shadow effect).

```css
.pbox {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<br>

<input type="text" name="txt" class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">

<br>
   
<div class="pbox">
    <b>Notice:</b>
    <br>
    You can't delete items without being logged-in.
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bring drop shadow effect for a div on mouseover using jQuery / Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410700/how-to-bring-drop-shadow-effect-for-a-div-on-mouseover-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Do you want glow on input or on div when you hover over div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to add hover CSS, try the following

```css
.pbox {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.pbox:hover {
  border-color:  rgba(82,168,236,.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(82,168,236,.8) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.8);
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<br>

<input type="text" name="txt" class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">

<br>
   
<div class="pbox">
    <b>Notice:</b>
    <br>
    You can't delete items without being logged-in.
</div>
```

Comment: Very good! But your glow has not the same color like input text's glow... Can you fix it?

Comment: @MinimalTech i grabbed a random blue - but let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @MinimalTech there how about that? If it is what you wanted go ahead and accept this answer for future users.

Comment: Yep, the trick is to use `:hover` instead of `:focus` for a DIV

Answer (score 1):

You can change `box-shadow` and `border` on `:hover`

```css
.pbox {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.pbox:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  border-color: #66afe9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" name="txt" class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">
<div class="pbox">
  <b>Notice:</b>
  <br>You can't delete items without being logged-in.
</div>
```

Comment: Please read more carefully my description. Your answer is not what I want. @Jordan.J.D. 's answer is almost correct - only the right color is missing...

Comment: I updated my answer this is same shadow and border as in bootstrap.